# C++ copying char to a char array (Debug assertion failed) says string is not null terminated

Tags: c++

Just trying to assign chars to the char array and it says string in not null terminated?

I want to be able to change the teams around in the array like a scoreboard.

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char Team1[7] = "Grubs";
    char Team2[7] = "Giants";
    char Team3[7] = "Bulls";
    char Team4[7] = "Snakes";
    char Team5[7] = "Echos";

    char TeamList[5][7];

    strcpy_s(TeamList[0], Team1);
    strcat_s(TeamList[1], Team2);
    strcat_s(TeamList[2], Team3);
    strcat_s(TeamList[3], Team4);
    strcat_s(TeamList[4], Team5);
    TeamList[5][7]= '\0';

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your array is uninitialized. also yelling "please help me" won't make us want to help you more (rather, the opposite.)

Comment: `TeamList[5][7]= '\0';` is out of bounds.

Comment: do you mean i have to put = int char TeamList[5][7]; above aswell or just put int in front of my array line of code

Comment: sorry for yelling lol

Comment: No, @juanchopanza means that arrays are indexed from 0, so the last index is [4][6]

Comment: The last element is `TeamList[4][6]`, and arrays are not zero-initialised. Look up arrays in your fine book.

Comment: ..and then give them up and use the std::string class and containers.

Comment: If anyone can fix my code for me it would be greatly appreciated its for school =)

Comment: Doesn't `strcpy_s` have three parameters?

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't think it matters if the arrays are not zero initialized in this case.

Comment: @juanchopanza I believe the message is from `strcat_s` not finding a zero to concatenate after.

Comment: can someone edit my code to work and send it to me tomas_munro90@hotmail.com so i know what the correct version would look like sorry to be a pain =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) (which is a "less-safe" version of strcat_s()) requires both strings to be null-terminated. That's because strcat() appends its second parameter (`source`) where first parameter (`dest`) ends. It replaces null-terminator of dest with first character of source, appends rest of `source` and then

> a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by
>   the concatenation of both

I would simply change

```
strcpy_s(TeamList[0], Team1);
strcat_s(TeamList[1], Team2);
strcat_s(TeamList[2], Team3);
strcat_s(TeamList[3], Team4);
strcat_s(TeamList[4], Team5);
```

to

```
strcpy_s(TeamList[0], Team1);
strcpy_s(TeamList[1], Team2);
strcpy_s(TeamList[2], Team3);
strcpy_s(TeamList[3], Team4);
strcpy_s(TeamList[4], Team5);
```

`strcpy_s()` does not have any requirements regarding contents of destination - only its capacity matters.

If you want to stick with `strcat_s()`, do this:

```
char TeamList[5][7];
memset(TeamList, 0, sizeof(char) * 5 * 7);
```

Then, this line:

```
TeamList[5][7]= '\0';
```

is not required, It is incorrect anyway, because for N-element array valid indexes are [0; N-1].

**EDIT**

Since in your case swapping comes into play, I would suggest you totally different approach.

First of all:

```
#include <string>
```

Then, initialize teams this way:

```
std::string TeamList[] =
{
  "Grubs",
  "Giants",
  "Bulls",
  "Snakes",
  "Echos"
};
```

Now, `TeamList` is an array containing 5 elements and each of these elements is an object of type std::string, containing name of a particular team.

Now, if you want to swap, let's say, teams 1 and 3:

```
std::swap(TeamList[1], TeamList[3]);
```

`std::swap()` is a standard C++ function extensively used in standard library implementation. It is overloaded for many standard types, including `std::string`. This solution has one, critical benefit: if string's content is held on the heap, swapping two strings is as simple as swapping pointers (and some length/capacity variables).

Oh, and one more thing: if you are not familiar with `std::string` and you would need to get pointer to a buffer containing string's data, you can do it this way:

```
const char* team_1_raw_name = TeamList[0].c_str();
```

See [this page for more info about std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: my question is Create a program that initializes a 2d character array with 5 team names. swap team three's name with 1 and then swap team 2's name with team 4's simulating a scoreboard. now the real issue i am having is my initial thought would be have one  2d char array and having all the teams initialized in the one array, but when i copy team 3 into team 1 and i then try to copy "original" 1 into 3  in order to swap the two teams i cant transfer value of the original because it has been changed, so i set up my char Team names to be put into the 2d array so i dont lose names when copying

Comment: does that seem like the best thing to do or is there alternatives ?

Comment: See update. If you are going to swap these names, copying raw char buffers will be a pain in the ***. Use `std::string` and `std::swap()` and your code will become clear and much more error-proof.

Comment: thanks man that helps heaps =) they havnt taught the swap command yet so im guessing they want us to just change it manually but good to know that the swap function is that easy =)

Comment: If you can't use `std::string` or `std::swap()`, stick with the original solution. But keep in mind, that you don't have to put names in second array. Simply use temporary buffer to swap two names. For example, if you want to swap `TeamList[0]` and `TeamList[1]` (assuming, that `TeamList` is `char TeamList[5][7]`, like you originally posted), you can do:
`char tmp[7];`
`strcpy(tmp, TeamList[0]);`
`strcpy(TeamList[0], TeamList[1]);`
`strcpy(TeamList[1], tmp);`

Comment: that is a better way of doing it like your saying just store the one that gets replaced into a tempory char place so i dont lose it right ,then copy it into where i needed so less bulk code?

Comment: That's right. You can make a function, that accepts two parameters of type `char*`, and encapsulate swapping inside. Then just call this function every time you need to swap two buffers.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` requires that there already be a null-terminated string in the destination to concatenate the source string onto; you're calling it with uninitialised values in the destination.

It looks like you want `strcpy` in every case, not just the first.

Also, remove the bogus `TeamList[5][7]= '\0';`. Even if you fix it to write inside the array bounds, each string has already been terminated by `strcpy` so there's no need to try to do that yourself.

Then stop messing around with low-level arrays and pointers. `std::vector<std::string>` would be much friendlier.

Comment: you are a LEGEND ! sorry for yelling =P